# How to change embed video size while playing in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, youtube

I have a `UIWebView` with size *250x160*, which should play video from youtube.com.

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/Y4Y_a45Bv20?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata";
        NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                               <html><body>\
                               <embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\">\
                               </embed>\
                               </body></html>", videoURL, self.web.frame.size.width-20, self.web.frame.size.height-20];


        [self.web loadHTMLString: videoHTML baseURL: nil];
```

While playing video I want to resize the `UIWebView`. When I make it, for example 2 times bigger, embed video stays how it was *250x160*. How can I resize it without restarting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try affineTransform.

```
webview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
```

or

```
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works, but webview video player controll transforms too and it not looks good, but Thanks anyway!

Comment: you can write some javascript code to change player size and execute it when you want to scale the webview. :)

Answer (score 6):

I found anoyingly easy solution :

`NSString *videoHTML =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"98%%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y4Y_a45Bv20?showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"];`

The key is in `width=\"100%%\"` and `height=\"98%%\"`. I didn't set height to `100%%`, because while playing video, it's strangely increases and after 10-20 seconds you need to scroll uiwebview to find where video is gone.

And don't forget set `UIWebView scalePageToFit = YES`;

Comment: You have solved a problem that nobody has been able to solve. I have wasted a lot of time trying to get this result. And you are right, 98% is necessary. Thanks, I have scored for you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach and it worked for me:

```
webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

[Auto-resize iOS WebView Helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/2)