# WKWebView embed YouTube scale video thumbnail

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I try to avoid this horrible output. I would like to present the initial YouTube video thumbnail filling the complete web view frame (WKWebView).

It is the white rectangle in the picture.

[image: iPhone screenshot]

My code:

```
import WebKit

class YouTube: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoID = "_g8aLVGXyc0"
    let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)"

    webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)?&rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

I try a lot of variety answers available on this site and Google in general.

Same output if you try:

width=\"(webView.frame.width)\"

height=\"(webView.frame.height)\"

Same output if you try:

```
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
```

Always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incredible, solution found! A lot of time wasted and I still do not understand how difficult it was to find this solution.

Inconceivable!

Here it is:

```
"<iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"97%%\"
```

Many thanks to this user:

[Neal Caffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3163238/neal-caffrey)

In this post you find the solution:

[How to change embed video size while playing in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956261/how-to-change-embed-video-size-while-playing-in-uiwebview)

The improvement is impressive!

[image: Final result]